# Angular: how to unit test changes to HostBinding property

Tags: angular, angular-unit-test

I have a component that dynamically changes it's role attribute via HostBinding:

```
export class TestComponent {
  @HostBinding('attr.role')
    get role() {
      return this.isListItem ? 'listitem' : null;
    };
  @Input() isListItem: boolean;
}
```

But I'm struggling to write unit tests to cover scenarios when `isListItem` is set to `true/false/undefined`.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = MockRender(`
    <app-test-component>
    </app-test-component>
  `);
  debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  el = debugElement.children[0].nativeElement;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should have the role `listitem` if isListItem is true', () => {
  component.isListItem = true;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(el.getAttribute('role')).toEqual('listitem');
});
```

Here is the error I get.

`Error: Expected null to equal 'listitem'.`

I was hoping by setting `isListItem` to `true`, and then using `fixture.detectChanges()` it would change the HostBinding in the tested component, but it looks like it's not.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a mock renderer - you can access the fixture directly -> fixture.nativeElement.getAttribute('role') should be what you are looking for. There's more on the fixture as well for other bound properties.